# How to click on next record in the column in a webpage in QTP

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have a list of edit button in the webpage. Can someone please help me to write the descriptive programming or through OR to click on edit button one by one.

Thanks

Comment: Like we have some methods to count rows in excel and fetch the data. But here I have say 10 edit buttons on which I need to click one by one.

Comment: Without knowing the structure of the controls on the webpage, it is almost impossible to give a helpful answer. The answer of Gunjan S implies the buttons are not in table cells, for example.
In other words: Show what you´ve tried, no matter how bad it is, and show a screenshot and a html listing of an as-simple-as-possible example AUT screen.

Comment: I have come up with the below solution:

Dim obj
Set obj=Description.Create
obj("micclass").value="WebButton"
Set x=browser("Name:=.*").Page("Title:=.*").WebTable("html id:=xxx").ChildObjects(obj)
For i=0 to x.count-1
x(i).click


Thanks a lot guys...

Answer (score 2):

Here it goes sample code:

Dim odesc, Webbtn, cnt

Set odesc = description.Create()

odesc("micclass").value = "WebButton"

Set Webbtn = Browser("test").Page("test").ChildObjects(odesc)

cnt = Webbtn.count()

For i = 0 To cnt - 1 Step 1

Webbtn(i).click

Next

Comment: I have come up with the below solution:

Dim obj
Set obj=Description.Create
obj("micclass").value="WebButton"
Set x=browser("Name:=.*").Page("Title:=.*").WebTable("html id:=xxx").ChildObjects(obj)
For i=0 to x.count-1
x(i).click


Thanks a lot guys... :)

Comment: So you picked up the idea of the answer to create the solution, right? Then this answer probably was useful and the most helpful one. Then please! accept it so the answer is tagged as "answered" (and Gunjan gets the respect points he deserves :-) ).